# Excel – как красить строки по условию?

Tags: excel

Есть шаблон страницы в экселе, куда добавляются данные.

В первом столбце данные идет с инкрементом, но между инкрементами могут быть «дубли», то есть

```
1
2
2
2
3
3
4
5
```

и т.д.

Мне нужно автоматически закрашивать определенным цветом каждое начало нового инкремента в первом столбце (красить всю строку).

То есть закрашенными будут:

```
1 //Красить
2 //Красить
2
2
3 //Красить
3
4 //Красить
5 //Красить
```

и т.д.

Как я понял, нужно использовать Формат/Условное форматирование, там указывать цвет и формулу, по которой все будет краситься.

Какую использовать формулу для такой задачи?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не нужно в одну тему валить несколько разных вопросов

Comment: Поправил. А у вас есть решение по вопросу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Закладка *Главная-Условное форматирование-Создать правило-Использовать формулу...*

```
=$A2<>$A1
```

Задать нужный формат, *ОК*, указать диапазон, к которому применять форматирование (П*рименяется к...*), например:

```
=$A$2:$A$99
```

Comment: Добавлю более точный ответ под мой вопрос, может кому пригодится: =$A15<>$A14